# how to show UIActivityIndicatorView for tableview that loads

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

A fairly short question, How can I load a UIActivityIndicatorView for say 0.5 seconds from when the view loads?

I have had a look around but most tutorials are using the webview where an if statment is created where (webview.loading) is used to define the length of the animation etc..
so i am just woundering how to do this when ever the view loads for .5 second.

Currently I have a method that centers the previously selected cell which I would like the indicator to last untill this is done.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self performSelector:@selector(scrollToRowAtIndexPath) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}

- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath
{    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:oldCheckedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: sorry but do you want the activity indicator to appear when the view loads/appears or when the tableView loads its data?

Comment: I would like it to load when the tableview loads the data.. but even then I would like to delay it for a little bit longer, as in some instances I center a previously selected cell. I am just not sure what the best way about doing this would be.

Comment: I have updated my question with some code about how I am setting up the scrollToRowAtIndexPath, I would like the UIIndicator to start as soon as the tableview appears untill this is method has been executed

Comment: you could call the activity indicator to display on viewWillAppear or every time you call [tableView reloadData] and then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method determine the last cell in the table is set up and then remove the activity indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe some like that helps:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //... all your previous charge.

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

    activity.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

    activity.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    [yourTable addSubview:activity];

    [activity startAnimating];

    [activity performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

    [activity release];
}
```

Comment: couldnt get this to work.. where you say yourTable I replaced that with self.tableView would that cause a problem. also I have ARC on so I removed the bottom line.

Comment: This is not tie to the tableView, it's just displaying a spinner for half a second